# smallest footprint for Web Application server?

Tags: web-applications

There are times when you need to spare hardware resources (either
to keep using legacy hardware, to play the embedded card, or just
to be efficient because a large footprint is trashing CPU caches,
leading to unacceptable levels of idle-states).

In this spirit, some efforts have been made to make 'light' ports
of Java or Mono (C# for Linux), and they range in the 80-50 MB
(instead of the 100-200 MB).

Add a Web server (Apache, IIS, etc.) to the scripting engine and
you can happily dive into the GB (IIS + .Net) only to load the
tool in memory.

Anybody with more modest tools in the specs area?

Answer (score 1):

[lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) + [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) should be pretty lightweight.

Comment: Good point! That's much better than the mainstream solutions.

Comment: Oops! Just forgot G-WAN's 120 KB. Hard to beat this one.

Answer (score 1):

[nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) is known for it's superb performance and low resource usage (about 2.4 MB the last time I heard of it). The down side is, you appearently have to recompile the whole server, if you want to include a new module.

As for languages, I always like to point everyone (especially web developers) to [haXe](http://haxe.org/doc/intro), for a number of reasons. In this case, because the [NekoVM](http://nekovm.org/) is a possible target. It has quite a low footprint, decent speed and allows in-memory persistency. However there's currently no way to run NekoVM on an nginx server. Which gives you the chance to step in and become a hero ;-)

Also haXe's C++ backend will soon be worked on to be suitable for web server development. As you seem to have experience with C++, this may be of interest to you.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find comparisons which help to decide, but the tests below use the same tool and procedure used by the Open-Source [Phoronix benchmark](http://openbenchmarking.org/test/pts/apache-1.4.0).

Here are a couple of performance/CPU/RAM comparisons of Nginx, Lighttpd and G-WAN available [here](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/serving-small-static-files-which-server-to-use/) and [there](http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/525/webserver-scalability-varnish-nginx-lighttpd-g-wan-rpscpuram).

Both tests use different clients (`ab` is single-thread and `weighttp`, made by Lighttpd, is multi-thread), different CPUs (an `i3 dual-Core CPU` vs a `XEON CPU with 6 Cores`) and different versions of the servers, but the hierarchy is the same (except for the memory footprint: in this matter, the second test's winner is different from the first test).

The smallest footprint comes with G-WAN (a 150 KB process) which supports `Java`, `C`, `C++`, `D`, and `Objective-C` `scripts` natively while others require to use FastCGI backends.